# Understanding Merge Sort Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, recursion, data-structures, mergesort

I'm going through the merge sort algorithm and trying to understand its approach recursively using this piece of algorithm:

```
MergeSort(A, p, r)
If p > r 
    return;
q = (p+r)/2;
mergeSort(A, p, q) 
mergeSort(A, q+1, r)
merge(A, p, q, r)
```

I tried to dry run this for an array of size 3.

```
[0,1,2]
mergesort(A,0,2)----[0,1,2]
mergesort(A,0,1)----[0,1]
mergesort(A,0,0)----[0]
mergesort(A,1,2)----[1,2]
mergesort(A,2,2)----[2]
merge(A,0,1,2)
```

Though I'm able to understand its basic divide and conquer technique but I'm not able to dry run properly.I know I'm missing something.Can anybody help me or point out the missing part.

Please note that I'm only concerned about how to dry run this algorithm.

Comment: Can you try to explain what's wrong with your code and state a clear question? Currently, I'm afraid it's not very clear.

Comment: Perhaps try it on an array which is not already sorted.

Comment: @maxpaj The piece of code seems right to me.My concern is with the dry running of this algorithm using pen and paper which I'm getting confused about.

Comment: Look at the animation on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) and see if that helps.

Comment: You're missing that each `mergesort` ends with a `merge`. Since there are 5 calls to `mergesort` there should also be 5 calls to `merge` in your runthrough, except for the calls that take the early return.

Comment: @MarkRansom - that should be each pair of calls to mergesort (for left and right half) is followed by a call to merge. Note that no merge operations occur until recursion produces two runs of 1 element each, then the merging process continues, left / depth first.

Comment: @rcgldr can you please explain this using an example or dry run the same step by step.

Answer (score 2):

The if needs a fix:

```
MergeSort(A, p, r)
If p >= r 
    return;
q = (p+r)/2;
mergeSort(A, p, q) 
mergeSort(A, q+1, r)
merge(A, p, q, r)
```

example dry run, with indentation for level of recursion

```
[0,1,2]
mergesort(A,0,2)--------[0,1,2]
  mergesort(A,0,1)------[0,1]
    mergesort(A,0,0)----[0]
    mergesort(A,1,1)----[1]
    merge(A,0,0,1)------[0]+[1]
  mergesort(A,2,2)------[2]
  merge(A,0,1,2)--------[0,1]+[2]
```

Changing the variables to b (beginning), e (end = last + 1), m (middle)

```
MergeSort(A, b, e)
If (e - b) < 2
    return;
m = (b+e)/2;
mergeSort(A, b, m) 
mergeSort(A, m, e)
merge(A, b, m, e)
```

example dry run

```
[0,1,2]
mergesort(A,0,3)--------[0,1,2]
  mergesort(A,0,1)------[0]
  mergesort(A,1,3)------[1,2]
    mergesort(A,1,2)----[1]
    mergesort(A,2,3)----[2]
    merge(A,1,2,3)------[1]+[2]
  merge(A,0,1,3)--------[0]+[1,2]
```

another example dry run

```
[0,1,2,3]
mergesort(A,0,4)--------[0,1,2,3]
  mergesort(A,0,2)------[0,1]
    mergesort(A,0,1)----[0]
    mergesort(A,1,2)----[1]
    merge(A,0,1,2)------[0]+[1]
  mergesort(A,2,4)------[2,3]
    mergesort(A,2,3)----[2]
    mergesort(A,3,4)----[3]
    merge(A,2,3,4)------[2]+[3]
  merge(A,0,2,4)--------[0,1]+[2,3]
```

Comment: One Question here: Per my understanding, After mergesort(A,0,0) it would return.So mergeSort(A, q+1, r) should be called and r is never updated.Basically how did you conclude the next step to be mergesort(A,1,1).Can you please update that which of the two functions i.e., mergeSort(A, p, q) and
mergeSort(A, q+1, r) is getting called at which step.

Comment: @AnkushDutt - the issue with that is with each level of recursion, you get a new set of p, q, r. So follow the sequence of calls at the same level of recursion (indentation in my examples), which will always be | mergesort(A,p,q) | mergesort(A,q+1, r) | merge(A,p,q,r) | , For the 1st level of recursion, mergesort(A,0,0) == mergesort(A,p,q), and mergesort(A,1,1) == mergesort(A,q+1,r).